# adding multiple values to colums in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created two colums using **System.Windows.Forms.ListView**

```
#   Spalten für ListView
$Columns                      =@('Process','Process ID')
#   Globale Variable für ListView der Tabpage TabPageOCLRA
$global:ListviewOCLRA               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$global:ListviewOCLRA.Clear()
$global:ListviewOCLRA.View          = 'Details'
$global:ListviewOCLRA.Top           = 20
$global:ListviewOCLRA.autosize      = $true
#   Ganze Zeile markieren
$global:ListviewOCLRA.FullRowSelect = $true 
$global:ListviewOCLRA.Anchor        = "Top,Bottom,Left"
$global:ListviewOCLRA.dock          = "fill"
#$global:ListviewOCLRA.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("arial",20)
foreach ($Column in $Columns){ 
    [void]$global:ListviewOCLRA.Columns.Add($Column,-2)
}
```

How can I tell the script to add multiple values from an arraylist to the colum "Process" and another range of values from another arraylist to the column "Process ID"?

I couldn't find out, how to choose the column that get a specific value.

Comment: But if these values come from two different arrays, how can you tell if the `Process` belongs to the `Process ID` ?? How did you create those separate arrays and why not use a Hashtable or array of objects for this?

Comment: i can also put process and process id into one array. how can i make it possible now?